# I installed some software like Docker, Jenkins etc on my PC but it's not working, all it's showing is that Docker-Desktop depends on qemu-system-86

Tags: apt, dpkg, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, archive

I've being trying to install it but this is what I've been getting as response

```
ife@ife-HP-ProBook-6560b:~$ sudo apt-get install qemu-system-x86
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  docker-scan-plugin libqrencode4 pass pigz qrencode slirp4netns tree uidmap
  xclip
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  samba vde2
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  qemu-system-x86
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 33 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/6,735 kB of archives.
After this operation, 32.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
E: Invalid archive member header
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/qemu-system-x86_1%3a4.2-3ubuntu6.24_amd64.deb
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 161767 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../qemu-system-x86_1%3a4.2-3ubuntu6.24_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ipxe-qemu (1.0.0+git-20190109.133f4c4-0ubuntu3.2) over (1.0.0+git-20190109.133f4c4-0ubuntu3.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qemu-kvm:
 qemu-kvm depends on qemu-system-x86 (= 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.24); however:
  Package qemu-system-x86 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package qemu-kvm (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up ipxe-qemu (1.0.0+git-20190109.133f4c4-0ubuntu3.2) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 qemu-kvm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Perhaps first try to purge and reinstall the damaged package: `sudo apt autoremove --purge qemu-system-x86` and `sudo apt install qemu-system-x86`

Comment: I tried but this is what I got:`ife@ife-HP-ProBook-6560b:~$ sudo apt autoremove --purge qemu-system-x86
[sudo] password for ife: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'qemu-system-x86' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qemu-kvm : Depends: qemu-system-x86 (= 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.24) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

Answer (score 0):

```
E: Invalid archive member header
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/qemu-system-x86_1%3a4.2-3ubuntu6.24_amd64.deb
```

I believe those are the important lines in your output. The qemu-system-x86 package may have gotten corrupted during download. First clear the apt cache:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Then update the package list and try to finish any pending installs:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Your output says *Package qemu-system-x86 is not installed*, so i don't think there is any need to remove/purge qemu-system-x86.

If the above commands are successful, then try to install qemu-system-x86 again. If those commands give you errors, please post them here.

Once everything else is fixed, you can run `sudo apt autoremove` to remove unneeded packages.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance it worked, I was able to install qemu-system-x86. I'll install docker-desktop now and get back to you